# Arch Linux Domain resolution stopped working

Tags: linux, dns, arch-linux, nslookup, resolv.conf

After a system upgrade (pacman -Syu) today, no domain names can be looked up. Networking is working fine, I can "ping 8.8.8.8" and ping "1.1.1.1" which are my DNS servers. However, "ping google.com" or any other domains do not work.
Any help is appreciated.

My /etc/resolv.conf:

```
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
# Too many DNS servers configured, the following entries may be ignored.
nameserver 9.9.9.9
search .
```

All the IP-Adresses CAN be pinged

```
dig google.com:
;; communications error to 1.1.1.1#53: timed out
;; communications error to 1.1.1.1#53: timed out
;; communications error to 1.1.1.1#53: timed out
;; communications error to 1.1.1.1#53: timed out
;; communications error to 8.8.8.8#53: timed out

; <<>> DiG 9.18.11 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; no servers could be reached


systemctl status systemd-resolved.service

Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-02-16 17:10:03 CET; 10min ago
Feb 16 17:19:28 brainysrv systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Got notification message from PID 459 (WATCHDOG=1)
Feb 16 17:19:45 brainysrv systemd-resolved[459]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 9.9.9.9.
Feb 16 17:19:59 brainysrv systemd-resolved[459]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 1.1.1.1.
Feb 16 17:20:05 brainysrv systemd-resolved[459]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
Feb 16 17:20:09 brainysrv systemd-resolved[459]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 1.1.1.1.
Feb 16 17:20:17 brainysrv systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Got notification message from PID 459 (WATCHDOG=1)
Feb 16 17:20:20 brainysrv systemd-resolved[459]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 1.1.1.1.
Feb 16 17:20:30 brainysrv systemd-resolved[459]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 1.1.1.1.
Feb 16 17:20:40 brainysrv systemd-resolved[459]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server 1.1.1.1.
Feb 16 17:20:52 brainysrv systemd-resolved[459]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server 9.9.9.9.
```

Comment: Does it start working again for a while if you do `systemctl restart systemd-resolved`? Try some of the solutions here and in the rest of this thread:  https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/13432#issuecomment-1078589970 . Seems like resolved can get stuck in degraded mode in certain situations

Comment: No, `systemctl restart systemd-resolved` does not help. I looked at the thread and was not able to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

- If you use VPN, it's a bug:  [DNS lookup fails while VPN is switched on](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/mozilla-vpn-client/issues/3003)
- [Try setting](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=240427) `DNSSEC=no` or `DNSSEC=allow-downgrade` in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`
- Temporary work-around: try a [live Arch USB](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-bootable-usb-for-arch-linux/). If that works, you might also try to find the relevant differences in files between the installed OS and USB version (finding the *relevant* one might be a pain -- I'd start with resolved.conf).